# Can you tell me what the less<pointer> does in this map typedef

Tags: c++, dictionary, typedef

I'm looking at some code written by someone else trying to bug fix and have this type definition

```
typedef map<RPacket *, CLocalLink *, less<RPacket *> > CPacketToLocalLinkMap;
```

I'm not sure what the `less<RPacket *>` is doing

Comment: See [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) and [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). And for this case, `less<RPacket *>` isn't even needed to be specified, as it's the default.

Comment: Could your  bug possibly be that comparing two _pointers_ is likely meaningless, in terms of the order into which the map will sort your keys, although it is a perfectly good key in and of itself.

Comment: my bug happens when a map insert is performed and I suspect one of the two pointers in the pair is a null pointer but when I was working through the code I noticed this and did not know what it was doing but thanks for the referances

Comment: @AlanJ If it's hard to catch the `nullptr` when using a debugger, replace `less<RPacket*>` with your own comparator that checks if any of the pointers is a `nullptr` before you `return std::less<RPacket*>{}(lhs, rhs);` - if you see a `nullptr` there, you've verified your suspicion.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to includes all the details possible about your "bug". And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Don't forget how to create a [mre].

Comment: a null pointer is valid to compare with `less<RPacket *>`. It will have *some* position in the order. Might your issue be you are trying to insert *multiple* null `RPacket *`s?

Comment: Hi thanks @TedLyngmo your suggestion did indeed show multiple null insertions as Caleth said thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

[`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a **class template** whose third template parameter named `Compare` is a comparison function which is used to sort the keys. This third parameter `Compare` has a default argument `std::less<Key>`.

> I'm not sure what the less<RPacket *> is doing

So, by explicitly writing:

```
less<RPacket *>
```

you're **explicitly saying** that this  `less<RPacket *>` should be used as the comparison function to sort the keys instead of the default argument(which in your case is the same as `less<RPacket *>`).

[`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) is itself a class template used for performing comparison which unless specialized, invokes `operator<` on type `T`.

> ```
> template< class T = void > struct less;    since C++14
> ```

As already noted above, in your case there is no need to explicitly pass `less<RPacket*>` as the third argument since it is the same as the default argument. This means that you can just write:

```
//---------------------------------v------------------------>no need for the third template argument
typedef map<RPacket *, CLocalLink * > CPacketToLocalLinkMap; //this is equivalent to what you wrote
```

Comment: Excellent thanks for a concise and complete answer much appreciated